# PublishContext.PublishMode.RootItem is showing the wrong item language version

Tags: publishing, publishing-service

When I publish the `Home` item, the selected language is `English`.
But in code, the `Root Item` is coming as `da (Danish)`.

[image]

On publish, for languages, I selected both Danish & English. So, is it taking the first language in that list?

[image]

How can I get the language that was selected, when the item was being published, i.e English in this case.

**patch.config:**

```
<pipelines>
  <publish>
    <processor type="MyCode.Handlers.AuditPublish, MyCode"/>
  </publish>
</pipelines>
```

**AuditPublish.cs**

```
public class AuditPublish:PublishProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(PublishContext context)
        {
            var rootItem = context.PublishOptions.RootItem;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. The publish job operation is independent from the context language/language selection the user has going on in the Content Editor.

Comment: So, I see `da` in the `RootItem`. Is it because is it the first language in the list of the publish languages.

Comment: Probably, yes. I don't think anyone has ever paid particular attention to the order these languages go out in since it won't really make any difference once the process is completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get languages which are selected in `Publish` window, e.g. get `Croatian`, `Dutch` and `French` in this scenario:

[image]

you can check `context.PublishOptions.Language`. Be aware, that if you publish in multiple languages, Sitecore will create multiple publish options and will process them one by one (it may be different if you use Publish Service).

If you need to get the root item which is being published in one of those languages, you can call

```
var languageVersion = context.PublishOptions.RootItem.Database.GetItem(context.PublishOptions.RootItem.ID, context.PublishOptions.Language);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to get the selected languages. The `RootItem` is coming as Home da but I selected English as shown in first snap. So, is there way to get Home en

Comment: You can try calling `Language.Current` but the output of this one may be different depending on where the publish call is being executed